# Fragment arguments don't set correctly

Tags: android, android-fragments

I init fragment using newInstance method.And then i try to get arguments in onCreate method.

```
public class ShowCostsFragment extends Fragment {
public static final String TAG = "ShowCostsFragment";

private static final String ARG_COSTS = "costs";

private List<Cost> mCosts;

public ShowCostsFragment() {
}

public static ShowCostsFragment newInstance(List<Cost> costs) {
    ShowCostsFragment fragment = new ShowCostsFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putParcelableArrayList(ARG_COSTS, (ArrayList<? extends Parcelable>) costs);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    Log.d(TAG, "newInstance(). Costs size: " + costs.size());
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mCosts = getArguments().getParcelableArrayList(ARG_COSTS);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate(). Costs size: " + mCosts.size());
    }
}
```

In MainActivity i run this fragment to show some data.

```
private void startShowCostsFragment() {
    List<Cost> costs = mDBHelper.getAllCosts();
    Log.d(TAG, "startShowCostsFragment(). Costs size: " + costs.size());
    Fragment showCostsFragment = ShowCostsFragment.newInstance(costs);
    showFragment(showCostsFragment);
}

private void showFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.slide_in_left, android.R.anim.slide_out_right,
                    android.R.anim.slide_in_left, android.R.anim.slide_out_right)
            .replace(R.id.content_main, fragment)
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .commit();
}
```

When i run method startShowCostsFragment the second and subsequent times arguments in fragment don't set correctly. The mCosts list doesn't change its value although the new value was passed to the method. And sometimes method onCreate does not call at all.
How to put arguments to fragment correctly when fragment dynamically replaced many times?

Cost class:

```
public class Cost implements Parcelable {
private int id;
private int value;
private String date;
private String description;
private List<Tag> tags = new ArrayList<>();

public Cost(int id, String date, int value, String description, List<Tag> tags) {
    this.id = id;
    this.value = value;
    this.date = date;
    this.description = description;
    this.tags = tags;
}

public Cost(int value, String date, String description, List<Tag> tags) {
    this.value = value;
    this.date = date;
    this.description = description;
    this.tags = tags;
}

public Cost() {

}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public int getValue() {
    return value;
}

public String getDate() {
    return date;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public List<Tag> getTags() {
    return tags;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public void setValue(int value) {
    this.value = value;
}

public void setDate(String date) {
    this.date = date;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public void setTags(List<Tag> tags) {
    this.tags = tags;
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeInt(this.id);
    dest.writeInt(this.value);
    dest.writeString(this.date);
    dest.writeString(this.description);
    dest.writeTypedList(this.tags);
}

protected Cost(Parcel in) {
    this.id = in.readInt();
    this.value = in.readInt();
    this.date = in.readString();
    this.description = in.readString();
    this.tags = in.createTypedArrayList(Tag.CREATOR);
}

public static final Creator<Cost> CREATOR = new Creator<Cost>() {
    @Override
    public Cost createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
        return new Cost(source);
    }

    @Override
    public Cost[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Cost[size];
    }
};
```

}

Comment: Use database or other persistent data store and load data inside fragment...

Answer (score 0):

`Cost` class must implement `Parcelable` in order to send it as bundle.

Edit:

If your `Cost` class was implementing `Parcelable`, you don't need to make cast, like you did `(ArrayList<? extends Parcelable>) costs`. 
You make cast, not implement.

`public class Cost implement Parcelable {` and the implementation. Take a look [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html).

Comment: It implement Parcelable.

Comment: Try get the list in `onViewCreated()`

Comment: I tried get the list in onViewCreated() and onActivityCreated() method but results are identical.

Comment: Did you implement `Parcelable` in your `Cost` class? In your above code you make cast, that's why you can't get values. Also try sending an `ArrayList`, not `List`.

Comment: I get values when i run this framgent for the first time. When i try run it for second or next times the value doesn't change. I updated the post. Added Cost class.

Comment: And you change values before second start of fragment? Hou do you do that? Explain the process, please.

Comment: I start application, get data from DB and show ShowCostFragment. Then in other place i add new Cost into DB and newly repeat previous actions. I newly get data from DB and show ShowCostFragment. But when i run it when the new data was added the values in ShowCostsFragment doesn't change. In the method newInstance() values are passed correctly but in method onCreate() i get old values.